# zsh: unexpected output from awk printf

Tags: unix, awk, printf, zsh

In bash I can do the following:

```
$ printf "foo\nbar\n" | awk '{printf "%s\n", $1}'
foo
bar
```

… but in zsh when I do the same, I get this:

```
$ printf "foo\nbar\n" | awk '{printf "%s\n", $1}'
[m\n", printf}'foo
bar
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I get the same `foo` (newline) `bar` output you expect. You sure you didn't make a typo somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I've typed it about a million times, tried loads of different ways of writing it, always get that output :/

Comment: Do you have an alias set up for it?

Comment: Nope. What I'm actually trying to do is a bit different to that - that's just the most simplified example demonstrating that behaviour.

Comment: turn on the local shell debugging to see if that shows any alias or function expansion happening, i.e. `set -vx`. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you by any chance using oh-my-zsh? there is a bug in the terminal setup that causes it to evaluate %-tags in commands like printf and date (and sub-commands `$()`!) due to prompt-expansion in the automatic terminal title setting.

Have a look in `~/.oh-my-zsh/termsupport.sh` and apply this change:

```
*** termsupport.zsh.orig    2012-01-31 10:49:57.503119973 +0100
--- termsupport.zsh 2012-01-31 10:50:55.043118110 +0100
***************
*** 24,31 ****
  function omz_termsupport_preexec {
    emulate -L zsh
    setopt extended_glob
!   local CMD=${1[(wr)^(*=*|sudo|ssh|-*)]} #cmd name only, or if this is sudo or ssh, the next cmd
!   title "$CMD" "%100>...>$2%<<"
  }

  autoload -U add-zsh-hook
--- 24,35 ----
  function omz_termsupport_preexec {
    emulate -L zsh
    setopt extended_glob
!   local CMD_1=${1[(wr)^(*=*|sudo|ssh|-*)]} #cmd name only, or if this is sudo or ssh, the next cmd
!   local CMD_2=${2//\$\(/\\\$(} # ')}
!   CMD_1=${CMD_1//\%/%%}          
!   CMD_2=${CMD_2//\%/%%}          
!   #
!   title "${CMD_1}" "%100>...>${CMD_2}%<<"
  }

  autoload -U add-zsh-hook
```

(Corresponding omz-issue https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/890)

Answer (score 1):

I am using zsh as well, and got correct (your expected) output.

There are a couple of  points you may want to check in your .zshrc file.

1. if printf is an alias?
2. did you customize your zsh with preexec()? for example to bring
   some colorful eyecandy for your outputs.

I guess point 2 would be the reason to your problem. since from your "wrong" output, the first part looks pretty like a color expression. If you find preexe() in your .zshrc, comment it out and try with your printf|awk again.

hope it helps.

good luck.

Comment: And - to be quite specific - problem was caused by [this bug in oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/890).